# AWS Lightsail for hosting Puppeteer; Won't run on the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppeteer, amazon-lightsail

As above,

I'm hosting an express API via AWS Lightsail. The api itself will work, returns test responses from Test query, but the puppeteer is not running.

I have done a npm install for the correct dependancies, I assume there are some issues with lightsail that means I need to install other ones. How can I work around this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the dependencies that were missing.

sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

If you have same issue.

Thanks!